# ProgrammingError at /db/ (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 252004:: Binding data in type (engine) is not supported

Tags: django, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
ProgrammingError at /db/
(snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 252004: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; 255001: Binding data in type (engine) is not supported.
[SQL: SELECT * FROM INGESTDB_DEV]
[parameters: (Engine(snowflake://etladmin_dev:***@xeroxcdp.east-us-2.azure/cpn_ingestdb_qa/ingest_admin?cache_column_metadata=True&warehouse=etl_nonprod_xs),)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/db/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
(snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 252004: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; 255001: Binding data in type (engine) is not supported.
[SQL: SELECT * FROM INGESTDB_DEV]
[parameters: (Engine(snowflake://etladmin_dev:***@xeroxcdp.east-us-2.azure/cpn_ingestdb_qa/ingest_admin?cache_column_metadata=True&warehouse=etl_nonprod_xs),)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
Exception Location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py in default_errorhandler, line 89
Python Executable:  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Priyanka\\Desktop\\Cogni_demo\\Department',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Mon, 28 Dec 2020 08:14:14 +0000
```

my views.py Looks like this:

```py
def snowconn(request):

    registry.register('snowflake','snowflake.sqlalchemy','dialect')

    engine = create_engine(URL(
        account = 'xxxx',
        user = 'xxxx',
        password = 'xxxx',
        database = 'xxxx',
        warehouse = 'etl_nonprod_xs',
        schema = 'ingest_admin',
        cache_column_metadata=True
    ))

    connection = engine.connect()

    ds= connection.execute("SELECT * FROM INGESTDB_DEV", engine).fetchone()

 #   df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM INGESTDB_DEV.CDDS_DATA.FB_HFSI_HIST", engine)

 #   cs = df.to_sql('test_table1',con=engine,schema='CPN_CNSLD_SEC_CORE',if_exists='replace',index=False)
    
    return df
```

Trying to connect snowflake database with django.

Comment: Can you try 

```# Create cursor cur = conn.cursor()
# Execute SQL statement
cur.execute(sql)
# Fetch result
# print(cur.fetchall())```

From https://medium.com/dev-genius/connecting-a-django-web-app-to-a-snowflake-database-855c16df590

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass in the engine as a parameter to the `execute` method. Here is some sample code:

```
engine = create_engine(
    'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/{db}/{schema}?warehouse={warehouse}'.format(
        user=snowflake_username,
        password=snowflake_password,
        account=snowflake_account,
        db=snowflake_database,
        schema=snowflake_schema,
        warehouse=snowflake_warehouse,
    )
)

connection = engine.connect()

ds = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE").fetchone()

connection.close()
engine.dispose()

print(ds)
```

Comment: i am getting another error after changing the code as u directed.

Comment: AttributeError at /db/
Could not locate column in row for column 'get'

Comment: Seems like you are calling the `.get` function without the correct column name or index.